# Redirect page with box input

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

On a HTML page you have a text box with a submit button. I need to know how to redirect to a specific number like:

- When is fill in 1 and click submit it will redirect to `www.website/page1.html`
- When is fill in 2 and click submit it will redirect to `www.website/page2.html`

and so on...

I use HTML/CSS only in website.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you give us an excerpt of your current HTML, so that we know, what we are working with, and a [mcve] explaining what you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I am setting this up, but can't find a sample code anywhere online. Starting from scratch just now.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a little JS first you can add your input field and button:

```
<input type='text' id='url' />
<input type='submit' id='btn' />
```

Then add your javascript

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", goToUrl);
function goToUrl(){
  window.location = document.getElementById('url').value;
}
```

This will take you to any URL, you could modify the pathname to prepend / append the destination:

```
window.location = 'www.website/page' + document.getElementById('url').value + '.html';
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out alot!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, your HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="url">
<button type="button" id="redirect">Submit</button>
```

And you want to capture, what the user types into the `input` field and redirect based on that.

This is, how I'd go about that:

```js
// register an event listener for the button. This can also be done using element.onlick
document.getElementById("redirect").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // get the number from the input field
  let number = document.getElementById("url").value;
  
  // construct the url to redirect to using a template string
  let url = `www.website.tld/page${number}.html`;
  
  // redirect the user to the new location
  //window.location.href = url;
  
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url">
<button type="button" id="redirect">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I use html/css only in website

I'm assuming you have jQuery or know some basic concepts from plain JS.

```js
// gets your form by id
var formElem = document.getElementById('your-form');

// adding an event listener for submissions
formElem.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // prevents the default behavior on submit
  event.preventDefault();

  // creating the variables we are going to use
  // and getting the value from the input field
  var redirectUserTo = null;
  var yourInputElemValue = document.getElementById('your-input').value;

  // checks the value and define the user destination based on the value
  // alternatively you may use a "switch case" if it fits better...
  if (yourInputElemValue == "1") {
    redirectUserTo = "page1.html";
  } else if (yourInputElemValue == "2") {
    redirectUserTo = "page2.html";
  }

  // checks if some destination was set before redirecting the user...
  if (redirectUserTo) {
    window.location.href = redirectUserTo;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="your-form" action="">
  <label for="your-input">Your Input</label>
  <input type="text" id="your-input" name="your-input" />
  <button type="submit">Submit this form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript or jQuery for this

```js
function gotoPage(){
  var page_val = document.getElementById('page').value;
  if(page_val){
    window.open("page" + page_val + ".html","_self");
  }
  else{
    alert("Please Enter Something!");
  }
}
```

```html
  <input type='number' id='page' id='text' />
  <input type='submit' id='btn' onclick="gotoPage()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you to use javascript

```js
function goTo(){
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value
  if(inputValue === '1'){
    window.open('http://www.website/page1.html');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
<br>
<button onclick='goTo()'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: This would only open ...1.html instead of 1,2,etc